# Java: IOException on write in HttpServlet

Tags: java, http

I've written a proxy of sorts in Java (and Jetty). Anyway, it works great, but sometimes

```
...
final OutputStream realOs = res.getOutputStream();
...
InputStream is = url.openStream();
int i;
while ((i = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  realOs.write(buffer, 0, i);
}
```

fails with IOException. I've noticed that it mostly happens with large binary files, i.e. flash and Safari browser...

I'm puzzled...

Comment: Can you show some real stack traces?

Comment: Do you get the exception on the `read()`, or the `write()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no stack traces. I mean, I try to print them, but e.getMessage() is null and e.getStackTrace() returns nothing as well

Comment: Maybe "-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow" helps with the missing stacktrace problem.

Comment: Please post the *text* of the IOException. There are quite a few possibilities and each one has its own explanation and mitigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if the browser is closed (or the user cancels the download) while you're still writing to the socket. The browser closes the socket, so your `OutputStream` no longer has anything to write to.

Unfortunately it's hard to tell for sure whether this is really the case - in which case it's not an issue - or whether there's something more insidious going on.

Comment: I'm sure that the browser was not closed - in this particular case, i.e. unit testing, I'm the user

Comment: So how exactly are you testing this? What does the client see?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can think of my app as a proxy. The client is a normal browser that sees a normal web page, loaded through this proxy. The problem - sometimes some objects like images and flash embedded in the web page are not loaded.

Comment: @Demiurg: Have you tried running Wireshark to see what's going on at the network level?

Comment: Maybe I'll try... the problem is that it happens once in a while and only on pages with lots of embedded staff... so it is going to be painful... thanks anyway

Comment: Eventually I discovered that the problem was on the browser side, 10x!